# ¿Cómo añadir la opción de volver atrás en Java Script?

Tags: javascript

tengo una duda que es que al crear botones no tengo idea de cómo añadir la opción de volver atrás, tengo que volver a empezar de nuevo o actualizar la página.

Comment: Te refieres al volver atrás que tienen los navegadores?

Comment: Volver atrás es un término absolutamente genérico... atrás a dónde? A la página de inicio del navegador? Al estado anterior QUE NO CONOCEMOS? A otra página? Al index de tu web? Cómo podemos darte una respuesta si no nos dices exactamente cual es el problema? No somos un buscador, de hecho, tenemos un buscador y también tienes google, donde puedes buscar cómo hacer cosas. Casi cualquier cosa que quieras hacer tendrá docenas de tutoriales en google y youtube. Si quieres preguntar algo aquí, mejor que sea algo específico y nos des los detalles, si no, solo es perder el tiempo. +info:[ask], [tour]

Comment: Y no está demás decir: **JavaScript != Java**.

Comment: @Benito-B, arriba de la zona donde escribiste tu comentario, aparece el siguiente cartel: "Romina Verza Talavera es un nuevo usuario. Sé cortés y por favor lee nuestro Código de conducta.", te sugiero que leas [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) "Compórtate bien." y [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct)  "Comportamiento inaceptable", cuando te dedicas a contestar preguntas, eres un gran elemento, has lo que haces mejor, y deja a los demás aquello que se te dificulta, aunque también puedes poner toda la carne al asador, y ser el mejor entre los mejores, Saludos.

Comment: Hola Romina, bienvenida, Podrías ayudarnos a ayudarte, si sigues las indicaciones que te han dado en  los comentarios, puedes editar tu pregunta las veces que sea necesario (aunque haya sido cerrada, en cuyo caso se re-abrirá), mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 2):

El `history.back()` hace que el navegador retroceda una página en el historial de la sesión.

Tiene el mismo efecto que llamar a `history.go(-1)`. Pero si no hay una página anterior, esta llamada al método no hace nada.

Un link:

```html
<a href='javascript:history.back();'>Volver atrás</a>
```

Botón:

```js
document.getElementById("go-back").addEventListener("click", () => {
  history.back();
});
```

```html
<button id="go-back">Volver atrás</button>
```